# What is the maximum data rate a wireless link can support using BPSK for given BER and SNR?

Tags: digital-communications, bpsk

What is maximum data rate a wireless link can support using BPSK for `10^-6` BER, Bandwidth of channel is `200 kHz` and SNR `21.335dB` ?
As per my understanding , `Eb/No` can be calculated for BPSK for given BER using curves and value found is `11.29dB`, and after that we can use relation

```
Eb/No = S/N * W/R
```

`R` comes out to be around `2 Mbps`! Is it correct? Need your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BPSK, BER is equal to $Q(\sqrt{2E_b/N_0})$, so you need $E_b/N_0>11.3$ to have a BER no larger than $10^{-6}$. Since the bandwidth is 200 kHz, the maximum rate is 400 kb/s. So, since $SNR\approx136$,

$$\frac{Eb}{N_0}=\frac{S}{N}\frac{W}{R}=136\frac{200\cdot10^3}{400\cdot10^3}=\frac{136}{2}=68$$

Since $68>11.3$, you can be sure that you can transmit at 400 kb/s and meet your BER requirement.

Note that I'm assuming baseband transmission (so that the bit rate is twice the bandwidth). Note also that the question, as posed, does not make a lot of sense, since the bandwidth will essentially determine your bit rate.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer.The design here is over specified. The point is we cannot specify all of these things: modulation, BER, SNR, and bandwidth.  Or else, it will cause a conflict. For example, if we don't specify BPSK, the resulting computation for finding the maximum data rate will be straightforward, and will also require higher-order signaling.  If we leave-out any one of the four items specified as fixed, we wll find what we desire without any conflict.